# How can I use the value that I received as axios as a value?

Tags: reactjs

I took the API value from child component to axios and handed it over to parent component in the form of `toParentUser`. In parent component, the value is `userInvalid` and it can be checked well in console. But if I want to use the value as a variable in parent component, but I try to use it as a variable, the error *userInvalid is not defined no-undef* comes out. How do I use this value in parent component? I'd appreciate it if you let me know thanks

**SignUpUserInput:**

this is child component. I received the value by axios and handed `userData.data.isSuccess` over to  parent component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import axios from 'axios';

const InputWrap = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`

function SignUpUserInput({userName,setUserName,toParentUser}) {



//validation check
useEffect (()=> {
  async function fetchData () {
    try{
      const userData = await axios({
        method : 'get',
        url : `https://cors-anywher.herokuapp.com/https://clone-instagram.shop:8080/users/checkid?id=${userName}`
      });

      toParentUser(userData.data.isSuccess)
    }

    catch(error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  }
  fetchData();
},[userName])
 
 
  const [isUserName, setIsUserName] = useState(true);
  const onCheckName = (e) => {

  }

  return (
    <InputWrap isUserName={isUserName}>
      <label className='inputLabel'>
        <input className='inputInput' value={userName} onChange={(e)=>{setUserName(e.target.value); onCheckName(e);}}/>
      </label>
    </InputWrap>
  )
}

export default SignUpUserInput;
```

**SignUp.jsx :**

this is parent component. I got value as `userInvalid` and want to use this value in this component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import SignUpLoginButton from '../components/SingUp/SignUpLoginButton';
import SignUpUserInput from '../components/SingUp/SignUpUserInput';

const SignUpWrap = styled.div`
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
`

function SignUp() {

  const toParentUser = (userInvalid) => {
    console.log('성공', userInvalid)
  }

  // I want to use this value
  const useThis = userInvalid;

  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

  return (
    <SignUpWrap>
      <div className='signUpInputContent4'>
        <SignUpUserInput userName={userName} setUserName={setUserName} toParentUser={toParentUser}/>
      </div>
      <div className='signUpInputContent6'>
        {/* want to use value here */}
        <Link to='/birthday' style={{textDecoration : 'none' ,color: 'inherit', pointerEvents: userInvalid && 'none'}}>
          <div className='signUpInputLoginButton'>
            <SignUpLoginButton email={email} name={name} userName={userName} passWord={passWord}/>
          </div>
        </Link>  
      </div>                  
    </SignUpWrap>
  )
}

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can not store userInvalid in useThis as userInvalid is out of scope so will be undefined so do this:**

```
const [useThis,SetuseThis]=useState('');
 const toParentUser = (userInvalid) => {
    console.log('성공', userInvalid)
SetuseThis(userInvalid)
  }
```

Comment: This was the answer I wanted. It works fine. Thank you so much!